# Unable to add new account in xcode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to add apple developer account in xcode 8.3.2, but unfortunately getting There was an error connecting to the Apple ID server. Also i tried to login with another 2-3 account but getting same for all. I tried all solution till now i found but no one works for me. Please help me on this how can i resolve this issue.
[image]

Comment: Did you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Delete expired certificates from Keychain Access, restart XCode and Mac and then open project and tick Automatically manage signing. It will repair profile and works good.